# Asked a question on the correct site, got moved to the wrong site, then gets closed

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question, closed-questions

My question was webmaster related so **I asked my question in [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)**, but it got moved to Stack Overflow.

[OpenID "AOL is unable to verify this website."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372798/openid-aol-is-unable-to-verify-this-website)

**It is not programming related** but the mods moved it to Stack Overflow where it got **closed for not being programming related**. So what can I do to have it moved back and reopened.

Answer (score -1):

1. It is programming related
2. The question is correctly answered by a dupe, [How do you get AOL's OpenID site verification to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505638/how-do-you-get-aols-openid-site-verification-to-work)

The only thing slightly incorrect was the close as off-topic (call AOL and ask them why their implementation is busted!), close as dupe is better and I have changed that.

Comment: He's obviously looking for a Non-Programming fix for this.  Just because the true __answer__ to a question is Programming Related, doesn't make the question so (though I think he could figure out what to do from the certificate answer).  It should have stayed on Webmasters, and pointed to the Stack Overflow question, so that future webmasters seeking NPR help on the issue could find the answer.

Comment: @Moak: [faq#bounty]

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ: Of course I know about it. but if my question is moved to the wrong site and then closed?